# fo:external-graphic with parameter in template file

Tags: xml, image, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm trying something straight-forward and I would say not too complex.  But I cannot figure out how to do it:  I want to have images in an XSL-FO document.

In detail:

I have two files, one contains the logical contents of my text, the other logically the formatting instructions.  I'm using the Apache application `fop` to compile this into a PDF:

```
fop -q -xml contents.xml -xsl formatting.xsl -pdf output.pdf
```

This works fine for pure text.  The file `contents.xml` contains things like this:

```
<part>
  Lorem ipsum bla
</part>
```

And the file `formatting.xsl` contains things like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ...>
  <xsl:template match="part">
    <fo:block ...>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now I want to add some images.  Because it will be many images which are all to be similarly formatted, I would like to have a simple abstract thing for each image in the `contents.xml` passing a parameter to a template.  E.g. `<img path="path/to/my/image.png"/>` would be fine, but also something like `<img>path/to/my/image.png</img>` or even `<img><path value="path/to/my/image.png"/></img>` would be okay.

The template in `formatting.xsl` shall understand and use the passed parameter and put it in a `<fo:external-graphic src="[parameter-value]"\>`.

Also, I need to be able to provide one of several formatting files to achieve different PDFs for the same contents but with different formatting (e.g. a paperback version, a hardcover version, and a manuscript version of the same contents).

But all my trials up to now have failed.  The only thing I managed was to have a solution without a passed parameter, so the path to the image then was hardcoded in the formatting file.

I tried a lot of variants with `<xsl:call-template>`, `<xsl:with-param>`, and also with `<xsl:attribute name="src">`, etc., but up to now nothing worked.  Either the `fop` complained about a wrong usage or the result didn't show an image in the PDF.

I have the feeling this must be something very simple and typical which many people want to do, but still I didn't find any example implementing something like my case.

Can anybody give me an example on how to do this?

EDIT:

My favorite usage in the `contents.xml` would be `<img path="img/001_title.png"/>` but in the `formatting.xsl` I have no clue how to formulate my template to make this work.  Without the parameter `path` I can use this:

```
<xsl:template match="img">
  <fo:block>
    <fo:external-graphic src="img/001_title.png"/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

But as I already wrote, this then hardcodes the path and cannot be reused to insert another picture with another path.

I also tried e.g. this in `formatting.xsl`:

```
<xsl:template match="img">
  <xsl:param name="path"/>
  <fo:block>
    <fo:external-graphic src="$path"/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

But then in `contents.xml` to *pass* the parameter value I was supposed to use sth like

```
<xsl:call-template name="img">
  <xsl:with-param name="path" select="img/001_title.png"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

which earned me an error from `fop`, stating that the `xsl` stuff was illegal at the place in `contents.xml` where I used it.

Also, the *use* of the parameter in the template as stated above probably isn't as it's supposed to be because I think this would need something like using `<xsl:value-of select="$path"/>` or similar but I don't know how to do that if the value is supposed to be used within the double quotes of an attribute.

For this, it seems the syntax

```
<fo:external-graphic>
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="$path"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</fo:external-graphic>
```

is supposed to be used.  But I also couldn't use this because, again, it is unclear to me how to *use* it in the end from the `contents.xml` file.

Comment: You did not explain how it fails explicitly, it sounds like its a path problem.

Comment: What do you mean -- a path problem?  The path to my image?  As I wrote, I tried a lot of combinations and none worked, often with messages implying that I'm doing it completely wrong, so I figured these messages won't help anyone who knows how to do it right away.  If it helps I can create a collection of the error messages.  But I think that anybody who understands my desire and who knows how to implement that would just be able to tell me how to do it.  I'm mostly missing a starter tutorial on how to do this, I'm not really encountering a weird problem with it.

Comment: Can you add an example of the `contents.xml` format that you would most like to use plus your current template for processing it so that we can see if we can improve on it? Please also indicate how that template currently goes wrong.

Comment: Hi @TonyGraham, I added a part to my question explaining in more detail what I would like, what I tried to achieve it and what the apparent problems were with this.  If you think the concrete error message `fop` returned would help you, I can provide that (from another computer, i.e. later).

Comment: What is the command line that you use with your XSLT processor to generate the XSL-FO file?

Comment: @TonyGraham I provided that in the Q above.  I directly call `fop` and pass the `contents.xml` and the `formatting.xsl` to two different options.  I guess internally the `fop` does what you are asking for (but how it does this, is out of my knowledge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be like your content.xml would contain things like:

```
<contents>
<part>
  Lorem ipsum bla
</part>
<img path="img/001_title.png"/>
<part>
  Lorem ipsum bla
</part>
<img path="img/002_title.png"/>
</contents>
```

Then in your XSL you use:

```
<xsl:template match="img">
<fo:external-graphic>
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="@path"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</fo:external-graphic>
</xsl:template>
```

Your XML can contain the images with paths and they can point anywhere and the XSL when it encounters one, it outputs it in the XSL FO. That template uses @path attribute directly from img tag in XML.

Then any type of path would work:

```
<img path="relative/to/something.png"/>
<img path="http://mywebsite.com/logo.png"/>
<img path="http://mywebsite.com/mycode.php?getimage='123242'"/>
```

Comment: Ah, yes, exactly that's what I thought.  I just didn't know this `@` syntax to access the attribute :-)  Thanks very much, this solves my issue as expected!  (And: still weird that this was not a typical example every XSL-FO tutorial would cover.)